# ValueError when importing matplotlib with iPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, utf-8

I am a beginner user of iPython with Anaconda and I have everything compatible with Python 3.5. I tried to import the matplotlib package to make a simple histogram and I got the following very weird error, an unknown locale: UTF-8 I have verified and I don't have anything in my program not in ASCII characters. Why do you think this might be happening?

Thank you!

```
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Comment: I forgot to add, I'm in Mac OS X Mavericks (still haven't updated to El Capitan, for which the problem seems to exist too).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to your `.bash_profile`:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

After these changes, run `source .bash_profile`.